# When attempting to install ubuntu 12.04 from CD, I am stuck on black streen with "loading bootlogo..."

Tags: installation, bootloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 to my desktop and burned to a CD using Infra Recorder and instructions on ubuntu website. Restarted PC to boot from CD receive black screen with "Loading bootlogo..." then nothing happens and I have to restart with windows.

The CD seems to be correct. Folders include .disk, boot, casper, dists, install, isolinux, pics, pool, preseed, autorun file, md5sum text file, readme.diskdefines file, wubi app.

**System Information**
   Operating System: Windows Vista™ Home Premium (6.0, Build 6002) Service Pack 2 (6002.vistasp2_gdr.120824-0336)
System Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
       System Model: Satellite L305
               BIOS: Default System BIOS
          Processor: Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  T2390  @ 1.86GHz (2 CPUs), ~1.9GHz
             Memory: 3062MB RAM
          Page File: 1553MB used, 4772MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
     DxDiag Version: 7.00.6002.18107 32bit Unicode
 Drive: D:
      Model: PIONEER DVD-RW  DVRKD08L ATA Device
     Driver: c:\windows\system32\drivers\cdrom.sys, 6.00.6002.18005 (English), 4/11/2009 00:39:17, 67072 bytes

Comment: Have you tried installing with a USB flash drive?